# onclick grab post values with ajax

Tags: ajax, post, onclick

I have set up some rows that when **open** is clicked it will do a database update to set the status to open ticket.

But for some reason i cant take the master $id with it? i need it to do some other things with it and prefer not to do a second query or JOIN on the next page just to get the master id.

i have this in my query ( i excluded all the connection code etc.. ):

```
<?php start query { ?>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?php echo $cid;?>" onclick="open(id)">Open</a>

<input type="hidden" id="REF<?php echo $cid;?>" value="<?php echo $id;?>">

<?php } // end query ?>
```

i have this in my ajax:

```
function open(id) {
var txt = $.ajax({
url: 'actions/open.php',
async: true,
type:'POST',
data:({
cid: id,
lid: $('#REF'+id).val()
}) 
}).success;
alert( cid,id );
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='view.php?mode=Preview&cid='+id+'&id='+lid;},200);
}
```

My problem is that it keeps telling me that id is null in firebug

If i change it to just grab the cid and do a test it works fine?

I have tried **document.getElementById** but for some strange reason nothing works?

Anything wrong with my code? am i missing something?

Thanks in advance :)
Jonny

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to make this line invoke `open`, and pass an interpolated variable value?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?php echo $cid;?>" onclick="open(id)">Open</a>
```

would become

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?php echo $cid;?>" onclick="open(<?php echo $id;?>)">Open</a>
```

Additionally, in your AJAX call, it looks like you are assigning an object with a key of `lid` to a value of `$('#REF'+id).val()`. Your hidden input tag however, has an id of `REF<?php echo $cid;?>`. Either pass the value of `$CID` to `open()`, or make the input field have an id of `REF<?php echo $id;?>`

Other notes: It looks like you are using jQuery to build your AJAX call. The you are specifying a `async: true`, which is the default option value. You can omit this from your code for better readability. Check out the default values at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: HI Ben, thanks for your answer. I have been so held up by other stuff that i have not had a chance to try your suggestion. I will mark your answer as soon as i get a chnace to test it out. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Have you had a chance to test again with these changes?